# Not able to select the row of table using selenium webdriver as div class is dynamically changing

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, extjs3

I want to select the first row of the table but selenium is not able to select table itslef as its parent div has dynamic classes which are changing according to the mouse events. Help me in selecting the row as i am all stuck.
Here is some screenshots:

**When mouse is not on the row:**

[image]

**When the row is selected:**

[image]

Comment: Please share what have you tried in selenium???? in which language??? and share your website URL if possible...

Comment: please provide more HTML code, importantly HTML above the required div element to help you. Use can use firepath with fire bug to find xpath. if relative path given by firepath contains dynamic elements, then select generate absolute xpath which will then provide absolute xpath. you can take help from this xpath

Answer (score 0):

As it is an **Ext-Js 3**(have to reverse-search for those class files from your screenshots and find it.Next time do mention the framework) Application, You can go with the relative xpath for first row

> //div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-row')][1]//td[contains(@class,'x-grid3-col')]

And as you haven't mentioned which language, Below is the **Java** implementation for sample **Ext-JS 3** apllication

**MCVE**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://examples.extjs.eu/one2many.html");
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(forRow(i))).click();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param index starts from 1
     * @return
     */
    private static String forRow(int index) {
        return "//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-row')][" + index + "]//td[contains(@class,'x-grid3-col')]";
    }
```